# recursive function not recognizing initial input in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching

This is an exercise in *Functional Programming in Scala*.

> Implement hasSubsequence for
>   checking whether a List contains another List as a subsequence. For instance,
>   List(1,2,3,4) would have List(1,2), List(2,3), and List(4) as
>   subsequences, among others.

My first try is as below:

```
def go[A](l: List[A], sub:List[A]): Boolean =
(l, sub) match {
        case (_,Nil) => true
        case (Nil,_) => false
        case (a :: as, x :: xs) if a == x => go(as, xs)
        case (a :: as, _) => go(as, sub)
}                                                 //> go: [A](l: List[A], sub: List[A])Boolean
go(List(1,2,0), List(1,0))                        //> res6: Boolean = true
```

This is wrong as in recursion the initial `sub` input was not stored (or not recognized) but replaced at each call.

However, if I used the function as a helper function

```
def hasSubsequence[A](l: List[A], sub: List[A]): Boolean ={
def go[A](l: List[A], a:List[A]): Boolean =
(l, a) match {
        case (_,Nil) => true
        case (Nil,_) => false
        case (a :: as, x :: xs) if a == x => go(as, xs)
        case (a :: as, _) => go(as, sub)
}
go(l,sub)
}                                                 //> hasSubsequence: [A](l: List[A], sub: List[A])Boolean
hasSubsequence(List(1,2,0), List(1,0))            //> res5: Boolean = false
```

Then it is stored as a value and works fine. Question is, are there ways of doing this if I don't want any helper functions?

**Update:** per @jwvh the second one need to be corrected as below.

```
def hasSubsequence[A](l: List[A], sub: List[A]): Boolean ={
    def go[A](l: List[A], a:List[A]): Boolean =
    (l, a) match {
            case (_,Nil) => true
            case (Nil,_) => false
            case (a :: as, x :: xs) if a == x => go(as, xs)
            case (a :: as, _) if a == sub.head => go(a::as, sub)
            case (a :: as, _) => go(as,sub)
    }
go(l,sub)
}                                                 //> hasSubsequence: [A](l: List[A], sub: List[A])Boolean
hasSubsequence(List(1,2,0), List(1,0))            //> res0: Boolean = false
hasSubsequence(List(1,1,2,0), List(1,2))          //> res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: third parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd solution isn't correct either.

```
hasSubsequence(List(1,1,2,0), List(1,2))  // res0: Boolean = false
```

As @Dima has commented, a 3rd parameter would help keep track of whether we have started a match sequence or not.  Also, we need to continue the search if the match sequence starts but fails.

```
def hasSubsequence[A]( l      : List[A]
                     , sub    : List[A]
                     , inMatch: Boolean = false ): Boolean =
  (l, sub) match {
    case (_,Nil) => true
    case (Nil,_) => false
    case (a :: as, x :: xs) if a == x =>
      hasSubsequence(as, xs, true) || hasSubsequence(as, sub)
    case _ =>
      !inMatch && hasSubsequence(l.tail, sub)
  }
```

This is not tail recursive but it is recursive without a helper function.

```
hasSubsequence(List(1,2,0), List(1,0))    // res0: Boolean = false
hasSubsequence(List(1,2,0), List(1,2))    // res1: Boolean = true
hasSubsequence(List(1,2,0), List(2,0))    // res2: Boolean = true
hasSubsequence(List(1,1,2,0), List(2,1))  // res3: Boolean = false
hasSubsequence(List(1,1,2,0), List(1,2))  // res4: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks @jwvh ! May I ask how important is tail recursion here? Practically would you spend extra time to make sure function you write is tail recursive?

Comment: Tail recursion is recommended if you have an extremely large data set. If the `l` parameter is a _very_ long `List` then a tail recursive method would be somewhat faster and it wouldn't throw a Stack Overflow exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hasSubsequence[A](sup: List[A], sub: List[A]): Boolean = {
    def isPrefix(pref: List[A], xs: List[A]): Boolean = (pref,xs) match {
      case (Cons(h1,t1),Cons(h2,t2)) => h1 == h2 && isPrefix(t1,t2)
      case (Nil,_) => true
      case _ => false
    }

    sup match {
      case Cons(h, t) => isPrefix(sub,sup) || hasSubsequence(t,sub)
      case _ => false
    }
  }
```